# Custom Shader Joyplotstlye

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

Maybe you could help me out here please: I'm trying to visualize a digital elevation model with a mesh and draw lines on it joyplot-style. This is done with a custom shader and currently it looks like the picture.

[image: Current joyplot visualization]

The black lines look blurry, but I want them to look crisp (no grays, only black and white). Can someone tell me how to change the fragment shader to achieve this effect?

This is the current shader:

```
function vertexShader() {
  return 
    varying vec3 vUv;

    void main() {
      vUv = position;

      vec4 modelViewPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewPosition;
    }
  
}

function fragmentShader() {
  return 
      uniform vec3 colorA;
      uniform vec3 colorB;
      varying vec3 vUv;

      void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(colorA, colorB, vUv.y - (5.0 * floor(vUv.y / 5.0))), 1.0);
      }
  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want black and white pixels, you just need to write `colorA` or `colorB` in `gl_FragColor`. Replace `mix` with the ternary (`?:`) operator:

<s>`gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(colorA, colorB, vUv.y - (5.0 * floor(vUv.y / 5.0))), 1.0);`</s>

```c
float w = vUv.y - (5.0 * floor(vUv.y / 5.0));
gl_FragColor = vec4(w < 0.5 ? colorA : colorB, 1.0);
```

[`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/mix.xhtml)  linearly interpolate between two values, but the ternary operator only selects one of the values.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`step`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/manglsl/docbook4/xhtml/step.xml), which generates a step function by comparing two values and returns either 0.0 or 1.0:

```c
float w = step(0.5, vUv.y - (5.0 * floor(vUv.y / 5.0)));
gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(colorA, colorB, w), 1.0);
```